# Powering a load through a small switch using N-Channel FET

Tags: mosfet

I want to power some load anywhere from 24-36v DC @4-7A, through a small physical slide switch rated at like 36v and only 200mA. So I need the small switch to activate a FET to control the power. The load may or may not be connected and it would be good to prevent short circuiting the load (when the switch is on or off).

Would something like this work, using an N-Channel FET? Any better ideas/ designs or improvements would be great help!

[image]

FET - [FDD18N20LZ](https://www.digikey.com.au/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/FDD18N20LZ/FDD18N20LZCT-ND/3908087)

D1 - [FSV20100V](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=FSV20100VCT-ND)

R1 - [CRCW1206300RJNEAHP](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-dale/CRCW1206300RJNEAHP/541-300UACT-ND/5326981)

R2 - [CRCW1206100RFKEAHP](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-dale/CRCW1206100RFKEAHP/541-100UCT-ND/2222931)

Sw - [EG2207](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=EG1940-ND)

Comment: Your load will still be at a high potential even when the switch is off. This could be a safety issue. Also, your solution add resistance to the ground path. If your load share ports with other circuits connected to the same ground, you could have ground bounce issues. That's why most of the time a high side switch is preferred. That [app note](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9093-D.PDF) can give you some guidelines for FET as high-side switches.

Comment: I agree that a PMOS solution could be better in some cases. The 100 and 300 ohm resistors are too low value and will get hot and waste power. I suggest making the values at least 10x larger so 1 k and 3 k.

Comment: High side switching can be done with NMOS provided you use a gate driver that can boost (i.e., one with a charge pump).

Comment: FDD18N20LZ does note seem like a good choice if you decide to do low-side switching. 0.125 Ohms * 7A = 0.88V of drop. Also several watts of power dissipation. If you look around, you can find NMOS with less than 5 mOhm Rds(on). Also, it would be better to drive the gate at 10V, irrespective of Vin. So you may look into using a Zener + resistor rather than resistor divider.

Comment: how about a reed relay? http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/89/2200_series_reed_relay_datasheet-594609.pdf

Comment: Vgs(th) ranges from 4V to <1V but for low Ron, Vgs must be > 3xVgs(th)

Comment: 400ohms is quite a stiff load on your power supply, over 3 watts at 36v, given that it only has to work for a few mS. I reckon that from the data sheet figures 6 and 11, you can deliver 50uA to the gate and turn it on fast enough (<200uS) to stay <50C rise in that single pulse of dissipation, at 7A 36v load. 22k for R1 and 10k for R2 will deliver 10x that on, and around that off, and dissipate far less power. If SW1 is a SPDT, then it could switch between a 10v capacitor and ground, the cap kept at voltage by 100k resistors

Comment: High side switching with a battery? Really?

Comment: @Trevor, sometimes it makes sense, sometimes it doesn't. If there are no external connections, then switching the low side seems more practical. But if there ARE external connections, switching the high side could be a lot more practical.

Comment: The other thing is sometimes people hook up chargers to batteries while the load is still connected. If the charger output is not isolated from earth, there could be unexpected sparks even when the small slide switch is off, if an earth grounded load is applied. Not sure how likely that is. But as usual, we are not getting the full story from the OP. ;-)

Comment: @mkeith yes, hence my answer. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is battery operated with no other ground connection, as you have indicated, it does not matter which side you switch. As such the circuit method you have indicated will work fine.

However, your resisters are far too small and the MOSFET chosen is under-sized and not driven hard enough.

You should bias the gate much closer to the Vgs MAX value. You also need to change the R's to Ks, that is, use 100K and 100K resistors for a Vgs Max of 20V. (Or whatever values gets you close to the max Vgs of your chosen MOSFET at the 36V supply.)

For short circuit protection, a simple fuse is probably your best bet.

---

If there are other ground connections you should use a topside PMOS transistor as shown below so the output is not live when the switch is off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYdpAr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Note** at 7A you will need a MOSFET that has less than \$20m\Omega\$ on resistance at the chosen Vgs value or you will need heat sinking. **The device you have chosen will dissipate over 5W at 7A, so chose again.**

**ADDITION**

Since you mentioned hooking up a charger to this thing, it is prudent to add some gate protection for the MOSFET, so I added and 18V zener D2 to the schematic.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. PMOS was what I had in mind. No worries I will change to your design above. A P-FET more like this?
[SUD50P06-15-GE3](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-siliconix/SUD50P06-15-GE3/SUD50P06-15-GE3CT-ND/1979016)

Comment: @zhjh yup that one looks like it should work.

Comment: Awesome. @Trevor is the 1N4002 an appropriate diode? I thought it would be slightly under-rated.

Also would there be an downsides to this layout directly connecting a battery charger to the circuit (on the load side)?

Comment: @zhjh 1n4002 should be ok assuming this is not driving a big inductive load, if you are you will need one that can carry a bigger current till it decays. Charger on the load side.. um.. should be fine I think, you wont even have to turn it on.

Comment: Thanks @Trevor. There are some inductive loads (motor, solenoid) . Would the original diode above be alright ?[FSV20100V] (https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=FSV20100VCT-ND).
I will prototype it up and let you know how I go. Thanks again.

Comment: @zhjh ya that will work, its a bit of overkill though

Comment: Do you think it would be adviseable to use Zener protection for the gate? ESD to the switch will mostly be blocked by the 100k, but if the input really is 36V, the gate may be at -18V when on, and the max is 20V. Just a thought.

Comment: @mkeith ya, I have been thinking about that all night, more because the OP wants to hook up a charger to the output. Addition added to answer.

Comment: @Trevor The solution worked fine. One issue I found was that on charger when the switch was off the Mosfet got super Hot so I stopped that. When switch is on the Mosfet ran fine and cool on charge. Any ideas on this?

Comment: @zhjh your charger current may be too high for the diode in the whatever MOSFET you chose. You can add another diode in parallel I guess.

Comment: @Trevor You mean another diode between the Drain and Source in parallell with the FET?
The charger has max throughput back at 1.2A. The P-FET I ended up getting was as above. (SUD50P06-15-GE3) [https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=SUD50P06-15-GE3CT-ND]. So what specs there have I overlooked. Source Drain Diode Current rating? p.2? The forward voltage?

Comment: @zhjh diode is 1 to 1.6V @ 1.2A so you are looking at 1.2 to 1.92W through the diode.